# Spring data MongoDB update multiple fields

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible with Spring-Data-MongoDB to update multiple fields of a document with one query.

For example, I can run this mongo query:

```
db.customers.update(
  {"firstname": "Max"},
  { 
    $set: {
      "lastname": "Maier",
      "email": "p.maier@example.com"
    }
  }
);
```

How can we achieve this with code and the spring MongoTemplate?
For example here is the code to udpate one value:

```
Query select = Query.query(Criteria.where("firstname").is("Max"));
        Update updateValue = Update.update("lastname", "Maier");
        UpdateResult updateResult = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(select, updateValue, Customer.class);
```

It seems that the Update#set method accepts only one (key, value) and no multi-values or list of values.

Answer (score 15):

> It seems that the Update#set method accepts only one (key, value) and
>   no multi-values or list of values.

Yes, it accepts only one key and value at a time. But you can do that for many keys and values as you want. It is like a Map, you can add as many keys(unique) and values as you like.

You just need to extend your code a bit

```
Query select = Query.query(Criteria.where("firstname").is("Max"));
Update update = new Update();
update.set("lastname", "Maier");
update.set("email", "p.maier@example.com");
UpdateResult updateResult = mongoTemplate.findAndModify(select, update, Customer.class);
```

If you dig deep into `findAndModify` method, you can understand, behind the scenes it is holding a key value map.

Answer (score 6):

In my version findAndModifiy does not return UpdateResult.
I had to use method updateMulti

```
Query select = Query.query(Criteria.where("firstname").is("Max"));
Update update = new Update();
update.set("lastname", "Maier");
update.set("email", "p.maier@example.com");
UpdateResult updateResult = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(select, update, Customer.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `findAndModify`.
Details and explanations there: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-update-document/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify

Answer (score 0):

Below is the equivalent implementation using MongoTemplate for update operation.

For updating multiple fields one doc object

```
   public Person update(Person person){
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(person.getId()));
        Update update = new Update();
        update.set("name", person.getName());
        update.set("description", person.getDescription());
        return mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, Person.class);
    }
```

For updating same changes to multiple doc object based on query match

```
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("city").is(person.getCity()));
        Update update = new Update();
        update.set("pin", person.getPin());
        update.set("description", person.getDescription());
        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Person.class);
```